# tinyMCE language change

Tags: javascript, tinymce, hebrew, lang

I'm trying to get tinyMCE to change language into Hebrew and I can't quite get it.
I'm loading the tinyMCE script directly from their site, and I have set a "tinymce/lang" folders on my server for calling the language files. nothing works.

Here's my code, it's pretty simple: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6j34g/)

```
<script>
tinymce.init({selector:'textarea', directionality : 'rtl', language : 'he_IL', language_url : '/languages/he_IL.js'});
</script>
```

Thanks ahead.

Comment: this fiddle is crap, there isn't even a tinymce js file loaded